# JQuery - Unwrap if element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have an anchor link that dynamically gets wrapped with a `<strong>` tag elsewhere in my code (according to certain conditions). I want to later remove this `<strong>` tag only if it exists. How can I do this?

```
<li>
<strong>
<a href="results.php">Next Page</a>
</strong>
</li>
```

The code I used to add a `<strong>` tag was:

```
$('li a').wrap('<strong></strong>');
```

As I said before, this only gets added based on certain conditions so it may not even be added. Which is why I only want to remove the `<strong>` tag if it exists.

EDIT:

In my code `$('li a')` is referenced as `$(this)`. I want to keep this reference so how can I achieve it by using `$(this)`

Comment: `$('strong a').unwrap()` ?

Comment: `unwrap()` can take a selector. If the (in this case `strong`) if the selector doesn't exist then nothing happens

Comment: First thing, your selector doesn't have single or double quotes to wrap the target.

Comment: I have editted it as I actually need it referencing $(this) instead of $('li a')

Comment: FIY, you could use a class, and just add and remove it on the anchors instead, and set the font-weight to bold with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if you are using jQuery 3.0 and above:

```
$(this).unwrap('strong')
```

If you are using an older jQuery version, you can do this:

```
if ($(this).is('strong > a'))
    $(this).unwrap()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('strong > a').unWrap()
```

In English: select all `<a>` tags whose parents are `<strong>` tags, and unWrap those tags of their parents (which, in this case, we know are strong tags).

Note that the selectors for `strong` and `a` can be as specific as you need.